# Response logging in AWS PHP SDK v3

Tags: php, guzzle, monolog, aws-php-sdk, guzzle6

In v2 of the AWS PHP SDK, I was able to setup logging of request and response information by simply doing this:

```
<?php
use Monolog\Logger;
use Guzzle\Log\MonologLogAdapter;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Log\LogPlugin;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
$monolog = new Logger('main');
$monolog_adapter = new MonologLogAdapter($monolog);
$log_plugin = new LogPlugin($monolog_adapter);
$s3_client = S3Client::factory(['region' => 'us-east-1']);
$s3_client->addSubscriber($log_plugin);
var_dump($s3_client->doesObjectExist('my-bucket', 'object-that-doesnt-exist'));

# This is the log entry I want in the v3 version:
# [2015-10-30 14:47:20] main.ERROR: myhostname aws-sdk-php2/2.8.20 Guzzle/3.9.3 curl/7.43.0 PHP/5.5.23 - [2015-10-30T14:47:20+00:00] "HEAD /my-bucket/object-that-doesnt-exist HTTP/1.1" 404  ...
# bool(false)
```

In v3, I cannot seem to find the solution. Middlewares do not seem helpful as they only fire before the request is sent, and thus I cannot access the response HTTP code.

Guzzle v6 has this feature built into its Middlewares, but I do not know how to get it to work with the aws-php-sdk. https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Middleware.php#L180

The closest I got was this:

```
<?php
use Monolog\Logger;
use GuzzleHttp\MessageFormatter;
use GuzzleHttp\Middleware;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
$monolog = new Logger('main');
$guzzle_formatter = new MessageFormatter(MessageFormatter::CLF);
$guzzle_log_middleware = Middleware::log($monolog, $guzzle_formatter);
$guzzle_stack = HandlerStack::create();
$guzzle_stack->push($guzzle_log_middleware);
$s3_client = new S3Client([
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
    'http_handler' => $guzzle_stack,
]);
var_dump($s3_client->doesObjectExist('my-bucket', 'object-that-doesnt-exist'));

# [2015-10-30 15:10:12] main.INFO: myhostname aws-sdk-php/3.9.2 - [30/Oct/2015:15:10:12 +0000] "HEAD /my-bucket/object-that-doesnt-exist HTTP/1.1" 404  [] []
# bool(true)
```

However, while the logging works, doesObjectExist() now returns the incorrect value because this handler does not throw an exception for 404, which the aws-php-sdk expects to happen. Some other simple requests like uploading to S3 seemed to work at first glance. Not sure where else there could be issues with this method.

Comment: An Initial cursory glance at how your S3Client objects are instantiated would indicate that the request that is being sent with v3 is not the same request that is being sent with v6.  The factory declaration does not include the 'version' option.  That may or may not make a difference.  Also, the 'debug' = true option is always helpful in such instances.

Comment: V3 requires a version be supplied, whereas V2 does not. There is only one version of the S3 API, so the absence of a version option will not make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handler used in the SDK is a bit different from the one used in Guzzle. You're creating a Guzzle handler correctly, and to pass that into the SDK, you would need to create an adapter like so:

```
<?php

use Aws\Handler\GuzzleV6\GuzzleHandler;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Monolog\Logger;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\MessageFormatter;
use GuzzleHttp\Middleware;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;

$guzzle_stack = HandlerStack::create();
$guzzle_stack->push(Middleware::log(
    new Logger('main'), 
    new MessageFormatter(MessageFormatter::CLF)
));

$handler = new GuzzleHandler(new Client(['handler' => $guzzle_stack]));

$s3_client = new S3Client([
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
    'http_handler' => $handler,
]);

var_dump($s3_client->doesObjectExist('my-bucket', 'object-that-doesnt-exist'));
```

The `GuzzleHandler` object converts HTTP errors to exceptions.

Comment: This worked, though I submitted an edit for the typos on "$new". Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

With aws/aws-sdk-php 3.212.7, registering a custom logger as shown by @giaour did not work for me.

The configuration [supports a `debug` key now](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/faq.html?highlight=debug#how-can-i-see-what-data-is-sent-over-the-wire):

```
$s3_client = new S3Client([
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
    'debug' => true,
]);
```

This shows the data transferred, but not the URLs used.